# CSS - advanced buttons with indication that its clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

The image attached is a snapshot from youtube. When the user hits the subscribe button, a small green checkmark appears on the button itself. How's this done?

[image: This is the snapshot from youtube!]

Comment: Instead of asking questions like this, please do some research first. Use the Chrome Console, Firebug, or the dev tool related to the browser you are using. If you can't use it, google it and learn it.

Answer (score 1):

```
button {
    background: url('http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/112/must-have/png/16/check_16.png') no-repeat 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
    margin: 10px;
}​
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2E22/). You need some way to make do the check if the user is subscribed or not, so you'll want some PHP or JS to look at your database or session var.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'd have done it too, though it seems youtube are using an image sprite inside the button (seems like the gradient BG has to be applied using background-image, which is a bit weird)

Comment: @ahsu I updated it to use jquery to change it from "sub" to "subscribed". This is a more complete example for what you're looking for. [Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/M2E22/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebug to inspect the youtube page, you can see how it's achieved:

Essentially, it's like this:

```
<button><img src=tick.png></button>
```

Although on youtube there's a lot more going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `background-image` property to the button, also have a `padding-left` and `padding-right` to even out the space.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4TFhC/2/) - Button with check mark styled.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4TFhC/1/) - Click on the button to see the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the button in Chrome, and selects "inspect element", you can see *exactly* how it is done through the css-inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The way they did it is a little different than what I normally see...

It's a `<button>` tag that contains an `<img>` tag. The img is just a transparent gif, but the img tag receives a background through CSS. The button class changes when you subscribe, and it changes the background image (css) of the `<img>` tag.

```
<button ...><img ... src="...">...</button>
```